# How to add a new data in ObservableCollection object?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

How to add a new data in ObservableCollection object?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Place> places = new ObservableCollection<Place>
    {
        new Place { City = "New York", Country = "USA", ID = 1},
        new Place { City = "Chicago", Country = "USA", ID = 2}
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Place> Places
    {
        get { return places; }
        set { places = value; }
    }

    places.Add(new Place { Id = 3,
                            City = "Miami",
                            Country = "USA"});

}
```

For some reason this part of the code doesn't work:

```
places.Add(new Place { Id = 3,
                                City = "Miami",
                                Country = "USA"});
```

Instead of that, what should I put there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot put statements in the class definition itself, put them in a function instead. Apart form that, having a public setter for your places is a bad idea: the ui won't be notified when replacing it

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This is the right code:'public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            AddNewPlace();
        }

       ...

        private void AddNewPlace()
        {
            places.Add(new Place
            {
                ID = 3,
                City = "Miami",
                Country = "USA"
            });
        }
    }'

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the code I can only guess. But does the Place class implement INotifyPropertyChanged? If not it needs to, so the collection is informed a change took place and the bindings can update correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know when you want to add your new Place to the collection.
But you can use a method on your view-model class like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    ...
    public void AddNewPlace()
    {
        places.Add(new Place
        {
            Id = 3,
            City = "Miami",
            Country = "USA"
        });
    }
}
```

You can also use the Places-property directly to add places from outside of your view-model.

```
viewModel.Places.Add(new Place
{
    Id = 3,
    City = "Miami",
    Country = "USA"
});
```

Btw: You should remove the setter on your Places-property because you should not change the whole collection from outside because this is an implementation detail of your view-model.